# Get User Info From Access Token WebApi Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using the new ASP.NET Core Identity API Authorization found in dotnet-core3-preview, the docs are found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I'm succesfully running the typical login process, and the token are set and sent in the Bearer token. However rightnow I have an api end point that should return some user details from the database, so I'm trying to extract the user id from the token to query the database.

Yet, I'm not able to find the id in any of the claims, as per my screenshot below, how can I accomplish this?

[image]

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByToken(){


            var ls = User.Claims.AsQueryable();
            return Ok(ls);

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user id could be find in claim : `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` :

```
var userID = User.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

That id value equals `Id` column in `AspNetUsers` table which created by ASP.NET Identity .

Comment: In my case, this is returning email insted of userId. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using this instead which is shorter:

```
var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```